# How to extract individual parameters from extRemes outputs

Tags: probability, probability-density, probability-distribution

I have fitted different probability distributions to my data. To compare the goodness-of-fit (GOF) and decide the best distribution, I use AIC as the criteria.  While I can easily extract GOF for the "fitdist" objects e.g.

> fit.gamma <- fitdist(x, "gamma")
> fit.norm <- fitdist(x, "norm")

> aic.gamma <- fit.gamma$aic
> shape.gamma <- fit.gamma$estimate[1]

and so on ...

But for

> fit.gev = fevd(x ,type="GEV") # this uses fevd (from 'extRemes')

while we can display fevd's objects using 'summary(fit.gev)', there does not seem a way to extract those individual parameters (AIC or scale etc) for their use in subsequent calculations.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is found in the extRemes manual by Eric Gilleland on page 55
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/extRemes/extRemes.pdf

1. Assign summary of fevd to an object, e.g.

> look1 <- summary(fit.gev.12, silent = TRUE)

2. Extract the objects as:

> AIC <- c(look1$AIC)
> BIC <-  c(look1$BIC)

and the parameters

> location<- look1$par[1]
> scale<- look1$par[2]
> shape <- look1$par[3]

Done!